# How to dynamically change a fieldLabel in extJs3

Tags: javascript, extjs3

Form fields don't seem to have an update method for the `fieldLabel` which can be only set as a constructor property.

```
{
    xtype:          'textfield',
    fieldLabel:     'Field Label Text',
    width:          465,
    name:           'field_1',
    id:             'field_1',
    labelSeparator: '',
    allowBlank:     false,
    value:          ''
}
```

I've managed to change it by:

```
var field = Ext.getCmp("field_1");
field.el.parent().parent().dom.children[0].innerHTML = "new Label"
```

But it feels kinda hack-ish.

Is there a proper way of changing the label?

---

Note: I know extJs3 is ancient history, but the project I'm working on is still using this version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just override the Field class to add a setFieldLabel method like below and then use

```
fieldObj.setFieldLabel('New Label');
```

anywhere in your application.

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.Field, {
    setFieldLabel : function(text) {
        if (this.rendered) {
            this.el.up('.x-form-item', 10, true).child('.x-form-item-label').update(text);
        }
        this.fieldLabel = text;
    }
});
```

Cheers !